# rows.sort is not a function where rows is an array of tr elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

What I am trying to do is to get sorting work for a static table with Flexigrid jQuery plugin. The r3 version of the file needs some patches to be applied so that sorting works for already existing tables and from one of the patches i found on the internet I got this code sample which I am not able to make functional.
This code is giving me some problem.

```
var rows = $(this.bDiv).find('tr');
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
                    var compA = $(a).find("td:eq("+col+")").text();
                    var compB = $(b).find("td:eq("+col+")").text();
                    if (p.sortorder=="asc")
                        orderby = 1;
                    return (compA > compB) ? -orderby : 0;
                });
```

The error i get is **rows.sort is not a function**. I looked at the sort function and yes it can sort arrays in alphabetical order. **rows** is an array of **tr** objects. Any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) returns a jQuery object and not an array of elements. You need to call [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) on that object:

```
var rows = $(this.bDiv).find("tr").get();
```